# How to remove properties in tab People of Mixpanel

Tags: ios, mixpanel

I've a issue with Mixpanel. As, when i used code ios.
Then i back to web to check. It occurred dups profile as image below

.[image]

Someone have any solution for remove that properties which are duplicated. Please suggest me. You will save my like. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, one of your platforms uses "$first_name" (which is visualized by the web app to "First Name") while another platform uses "First Name". Update the code to stop the duplication, and then you can use the API (or if the numbers are small, fix by hand) to remove the duplicate properties, as Mixpanel People profiles are mutable.

If you only did a test, and have only a small number of profiles with the incorrect property (e.g. from testing), you can delete the properties on those profiles and the dropdown will reflect the disappearance after a short time.